# How do I embed an image in a .NET HTML Mail Message?

Tags: c#, .net, html

I have an HTML Mail template, with a place holder for the image. I am getting the image I need to send out of a database and saving it into a photo directory. I need to embed the image in the HTML Message.

I have explored using an AlternateView:

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<HTML> <img src=cid:VisitorImage> </HTML>");

LinkedResource VisitorImage = new LinkedResource(p_ImagePath);
VisitorImage.ContentId= "VisitorImage";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(VisitorImage);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
LinkedResource objLinkedRes = new LinkedResource(
            Server.MapPath(".") + "\\fuzzydev-logo.jpg", 
            "image/jpeg");
objLinkedRes.ContentId = "fuzzydev-logo";       
AlternateView objHTLMAltView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            "<img src='cid:fuzzydev-logo' />", 
            new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
objHTLMAltView.LinkedResources.Add(objLinkedRes);
objMailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(objHTLMAltView);
```

Comment: Looks like link is dead.